# Metro Javascript. Error grouping items. ui.js firstItemIndexHint property

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Well, I'm pulling my hair out with an error grouping items to render in a listview.
When I set the items/groups datasources to the list thru WinJS.UI.setOptions I get an error in ui.js at line 16812 saying "**Unable to get property 'firstItemIndexHint' of undefined or null reference**".

I have other pages in my application where grouping works fine but this one doesn't seems to work. I use the same binding method in all of them and I can't find any difference between them that causing this error.

Can anyone tell me what's making the following code crash?.
Thanks.

javascript page code in ready function:

```
        var arr = new Array();
        //fill in an array with sample data.
        //name property is the one used for grouping
        //nm is rendered in the item template.
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            arr.push({
                name: "group" + (i % 5),
                nm: "namer" + i,
            });

        }
        //create a list based on the array.
        var items = new WinJS.Binding.List(arr);

        //group items by the name property (key selector function) and 
        //use it for rendering the group template (group data function)
        var groupDataSource = items.createGrouped(
            function (item) {
                return item.name;

            },
            function (item) {

                return {
                    name: item.name,
                    click: function () {
                        nav.navigate("mynavpage.html");
                    }
                };

            });

         //get a reference to the listview control
         var listView = element.querySelector(".itemGroups").winControl;

         //set templates and datasources to listview
         //here's where calls to base.js/ui.js are made and where app fails.
         WinJS.UI.setOptions(listView, {
            groupHeaderTemplate: $(".headerTemplate")[0],
            itemTemplate: $("#itemTemplate1")[0],
            itemDataSource: items.dataSource,
            groupDataSource: groupDataSource.groups.dataSource,
        });
```

html page code

```
 <!-- group header template -->
 <div class="headerTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <h2 class="group-title" data-win-bind="textContent: name" role="link">
    </h2>
 </div>

<!-- item template -->
<div id="itemTemplate1" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" style="display: none">
    <div class="itemTemplate item1x1" id="item1">
        <div class="itemText">
            <h4 class="itemTitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: nm"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- fragment section -->
 <div class="myPage fragment">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pageTitle">Page Title</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <!-- listview Grid -->
        <div class="itemGroups" aria-label="List of groups" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{ tapBehavior: 'toggleSelect' }">
        </div>

    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the groupDataSource for both the items and the groups.

```
WinJS.UI.setOptions(listView, { 
        groupHeaderTemplate: $(".headerTemplate")[0], 
        itemTemplate: $("#itemTemplate1")[0], 
        itemDataSource: groupDataSource.dataSource, 
        groupDataSource: groupDataSource.groups.dataSource, 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I solved it a few days ago but had forgotten this question so the credit goes to you :)

Comment: cool.. i think more people could run into this so its good to have the answer here

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver, couldn't find info anywhere explicitly saying the datasource had to be the same.